# Precise Highcharts xrange

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to make 'xrange' type to render data with an absolute precision that would look like the 'column' type? I would use 'column', but it only uses one 'x' value and I need start and end time for each bar.

I need the bar to stretch over the yAxis from 0 to the y value.
Each bar uses padding and goes beyond the max value in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/w5mhfp1x/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    styledMode: true
},
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts X-range'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 1800000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%H:%M'
    },
},
time: {
    useUTC: false
  },
series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    borderRadius: 1,
    data: data,
  }]
});
```

I think this version is precise, but I need the bar to stretch all the way to the 0:

https://jsfiddle.net/w5mhfp1x/2/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    borderRadius: 1,
    pointWidth: 1,
    data: data,
}]
```

Comment: Have you considered to use the `columnrange` series type? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y61w7a4g/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It looks like ```columnrange``` series type takes "low" and "high" as yAxis values. Is there a way to change it to xAxis?

https://jsfiddle.net/zasLc9eg/

Comment: yeah, sure, use the `chart.inverted` feature to achieve it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vgt5abjd/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted